# I cant figure out how to make it not say added view to list every time i type view into the command

Tags: python, list, sorting

I cant figure out how to make it not say added view to list every time i type view into the command.

or any of the commands that i can type in.

I tried to make it so that if you dont type the commands but it doesnt work.

```
# Declaring the sorting var

sorting = []

# Sorting the list

def sort():
    sorting.remove('sort')
    print(' ')
    print('Your sorted list:')
    print(' ')
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    sorting.sort()
    print(sorting)
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print(' ')

# Clearing the list

def clear():
    sorting.clear()
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print('cleared your list')
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print(' ')

# View the list without sorting

def view():
    sorting.remove('view')
    print('Your list:')
    print(' ')
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print(sorting)
    print('-----------------------------------------------')

# Quiting

def quiting():
    sorting.remove('quit')
    quit()

# Adding things to list and command functions

def append():
    sort_appending = input('type something to add it to list, type sort to sort your list, type clear to clear your list, type view to view your list not sorted type quit to quit: ')
    print(' ')
    if sort_appending != 'sort' or 'quit':
        sorting.append(sort_appending)
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        print('Added', sort_appending, 'to your list')
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        print(' ')
    if sort_appending == 'sort':
        sort()
    if sort_appending == 'clear':
        clear()
    if sort_appending == 'view':
        view()
    if sort_appending == 'quit':
        quiting()

# Main loop

run = True

while run == True:
    append()
```

If you dont understand me you could put it into your python IDLE and test it

Please help me this is a problem i need help with.

Answer (score 0):

`'view'` is being interpreted as an "add an element" input by this check here:

```
    if sort_appending != 'sort' or 'quit':
        sorting.append(sort_appending)
```

As an easy fix I'd suggest restructuring this as an `if...elif` chain so that you only do one thing with any given piece of input:

```
    if sort_appending == 'sort':
        sort()
    elif sort_appending == 'clear':
        clear()
    elif sort_appending == 'view':
        view()
    elif sort_appending == 'quit':
        quiting()
    else:  # any other input is implicitly treated as an 'add'
        sorting.append(sort_appending)
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        print('Added', sort_appending, 'to your list')
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        print(' ')
```

This prevents you from having to duplicate each "command" in that first check (and hitting bugs like this when you add a new command in one place but forget to add it there)!

Answer (score 0):

```
if sort_appending not in ['sort','quit','view']:
    sorting.append(sort_appending)
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print('Added', sort_appending, 'to your list')
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print(' ')
```

You already have the answer. Just add 'view' to this too!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution

```
def append():
    sort_appending = input('type something to add it to list, type sort to sort your list, type clear to clear your list, type view to view your list not sorted type quit to quit: \n')
    print(' ') 
    if sort_appending == 'sort':
        sort()
    elif sort_appending == 'clear':
        clear()
    elif sort_appending == 'view':
        view()
    elif sort_appending == 'quit':
        quiting()
    else:
        sorting.append(sort_appending)
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        print('Added', sort_appending, 'to your list')
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        print(' ')
```

Also change the following

```
def view():
    #sorting.remove('view')
    print('Your list:')
    print(' ')
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print(sorting)
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
```

Hope this helps!